# Formatting numbers using awk / print

Tags: bash, awk

I found this very cool code to get upload/download speed:

```
awk '{ if (l1) {
        print "↓"($2-l1)/1024"kB/s ","↑"($10-l2)/1024"kB/s"
    } else {
        l1=$2; l2=$10;
    }
}' <(grep wlan0 /proc/net/dev) <(sleep 1; grep wlan0 /proc/net/dev)
```

However, it returns up to 4 decimals. I rather have no decimals whatsoever. I have previously been able to round numbers using [bc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217570/bc-set-number-of-digits-after-decimal-point) or [printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632001/how-to-display-number-to-two-decimal-places-in-bash-function), but I seem to only be able to use `print` in `awk`. What is a good solution to this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/bin/awk -f
{
     if (l1) {
             printf("↓ %.2f kB/s ↑ %.2f kB/s\n" \
               , ($2 - l1) / 1024, ($10 - l2) / 1024)
     } else {
             l1 = $2;
             l2 = $10;
     }
}
```

`%.2f` is a floating point number with two decimal places. Use `%.0f` or `%i` (integer) to display just the integral part.

Answer (score 4):

Add `%.0f` to your print statement.

**Example**

```
echo "5.54" | awk '{printf "%.0f\n", $1}'
```

gives the output as 6.

```
echo "5" | awk '{printf "%.0f\n", $1}'
```

gives the output as 5.