# if (comparison var1 var2) "var1 not found" error

Tags: bash, shell-script

I've found this simple bash that illustrates my problem:

```
  #!/bin/sh 
str1="Learn Bash"
str2="Learn Bash"

if (( "$str1" == "$str2" )); then
   echo "Both Strings are Equal."
else
   echo "Both Strings are not Equal."
fi
```

And the result is:

```
    if_equal.sh: 6: if_equal.sh: Learn Bash: not found

Both Strings are not Equal.
```

Basically I want the if to compare the result of awk with a float once, and a integer given by user after, so when I can, I use

```
[ "$c" -gt "$o" ]
```

but it not works with floats neither I can loop it with a third variable like this:

```
[ "$c" -gt "$o" ] && echo fine || [ "$b" -gt "$o" ] && echo better
```

I've checked all spaces, tried with and without ", [],(),(())... I can't find why if finds that the first variable is missing. BTW my script created a file '0.9500' since I ran it with

```
if (( "$c" > "0.9500" ))
```

maybe there is the workaround?

Comment: See also: [What's the difference between single and double equal signs (=) in shell comparisons?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/72039)

Comment: [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306111/170373)

Answer (score 10):

In `bash`, `(( ... ))` is an arithmetic evaluation.  In the `sh` shell, which is the shell your script is using due to the `#!`-line, it is most likely being interpreted as two nested sub-shells.  This is why you get a file called `0.9500` when you run `(( "$c" > "0.9500" ))` with the `sh` shell.  The `>` is an I/O redirection, not a comparison operator, and `$c` would be interpreted as a command, which is what's causing your "not found" error message.

In the `sh` shell, if you want to compare strings, use

```bsh
[ "$str1" = "$str2" ]
```

If you want to compare integers, use, e.g.,

```bsh
[ "$num1" -gt "$num2" ]
```

In the `bash` shell, you may use the above syntax too, but could you could also use

```bsh
[[ "$str1" == "$str2" ]]
```

to compare two strings for equality, and

```bsh
(( num1 > num2 ))
```

to compare two integers.

The `bash` shell does not include the capability to treat floating-point numbers in any other way than as strings.

To compare floating-point numbers in the shell, you may use `awk`.

```bsh
if awk -v num1="$num1" -v num2="$num2" 'BEGIN { exit !(num1 > num2) }'
then
    printf '%s is greater than %s\n' "$num1" "$num2"
else
    printf '%s is not greater than %s\n' "$num1" "$num2"
fi
```

Note that the boolean result of the comparison must be inverted with `!` to convert it to an exit-status for the shell.

Related:

- [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786)

Comment: "[[ "$str1" == "$str2" ]]" So I can compare strings only for their equality or not? 
So I've made awk print the result as integer like in [the first answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131013/formatting-numbers-using-awk-print) and then I use `[ "$num1" -gt "$num2" ]`. Thank you

Comment: @Mona_Lu You were consistently using a greater-than in your question when comparing numbers, which is why I wrote my answer using the same comparison with numbers. To compare numbers for equality, use `-eq` in `[ ... ]` or `[[ ... ]]`, or use `==` in `(( ... ))`.

Comment: @Mona_Lu If you just want to chop off the decimals of some number `$num`, use `${num%.*}` (assuming the number in `$num` uses dot as the decimal point). `[ "${num1%.*}" -gt "${num2%.*}" ]`. This was not an issue in your question, so I never mentioned it.

Comment: My strings are float numbers like 0.9500 and 0.9378 and I want to compare if the first is greater than the second. If I got it right, I can't use `[[ "$str1" >> "$str2" ]]` and `(( "$c" > "0.9500" ))` is not accepted, so I have to work with integers or awk as @roaima mentioned below.

Comment: @Mona_Lu See update to the question. As I can't see your own `awk` code, you may want to do something similar within your existing `awk` program rather than using two shell variables to hold the intermediate numbers.

Comment: Technically, in the POSIX `sh` language, `( (...))` is a nested subshell, but `((...))` is [unspecified](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_01). In practice, some `sh` interpreter implementations either behave like ksh and treat it as arithmetic expression evaluation, while some others treat it as nested subshell.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks. I modified my language slightly, inserting "most likely".  I'm assuming the user ended up using `dash`, which treats `(( ... ))` as a nested subshell.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, `sh` doesn't handle `(( … ))`. You could use `bash`, but even then it's only for numeric integer expressions. See later in this answer for `sh`-compatible use of `awk`. I note that you describe your script as a `bash` script but you've used `#!/bin/sh` as the  header. This header declares the script as a `sh` script, which has slightly different syntax.

**If you're using `bash`** you should search the documentation (`man bash`) for `((` (you might need to escape the brackets, i.e. `\(\(`, if your pager requires it). You'll find this text,

> **`((expression))`** The expression is evaluated according to the rules described below under **ARITHMETIC EVALUATION**.

Search down for `ARITHMETIC EVALUATION` and you'll eventually read this (my emphasis),

> **ARITHMETIC EVALUATION** The shell allows arithmetic expressions to be evaluated, under certain circumstances (see the `let` and `declare` builtin  commands, the `((` compound command, and Arithmetic Expansion). **Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers with no check for overflow** [...]

What this is telling you is that the `(( … ))` construct can evaluate *integer arithmetic*. It's not for strings or for floating point arithmetic.

**Continuing now with an answer for either `sh` or `bash`.**

You can handle strings with `[ … ]` or `[[ … ]]`,

```
if [[ "$str1" == "$str2" ]] …    # bash
```

or

```
if [ "$str1" = "$str2" ] …       # POSIX including sh, and bash
```

Floating point arithmetic is harder; you have to drop out to `bc` or `awk` for this (my preferred approach is `awk`):

```
a=12.34 b=5.678    # These are strings

# You cannot compare them as integers, because they're floats
if [[ "$a" -gt "$b" ]]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
-bash: [[: 12.34: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".34")

# You can use awk though
if awk -v a="$a" -v b="$b" 'BEGIN { exit !(a > b) }'; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
yes
```

Here, we assign two `awk` variables `a` and `b`. Before `awk` has a chance to start reading from *stdin* we compare them numerically with `>` and exit with a status that corresponds to `true`/`false`. That `awk` exit status is processed by the shell's `if … then … else … fi` construct as usual.

Comment: In fact i modified the header after reading other questions here, before it was `#!/bin/bash`... The theory is not my strong, I pick solutions here and there (especially here) and I note your awk method for the next time!

Comment: @Mona_Lu you don't need [add complexity](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/671421/if-comparison-var1-var2-var1-not-found-error/671424?noredirect=1#comment1266585_671422) by using `awk` to print an integer result and then putting that value into `[ x -gt y ]`. Just use the `awk` directly as in my (last) example

Comment: In my next script for sure, but in this one it was more simple to add `printf "%.0f\n"` few times, than edit the if conditions this few times. So thank you for this method!